# how to convert hashMap into json object in scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, hashmap

I want to convert hashmap into json object, my hashmap structure is look like this:

```
def res=Action{ implicit request=>
  var response=new HashMap[String,Map[String,String]]
  response=//etc .......
  .
  .
  .
  Ok(write(response))
}
```

bt its not working .

Comment: Take a look [at the json utilities built into play framework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson), then apply the knowledge

Comment: it depends upon your requirement... can you show me which type format u want to get ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ok(Json.toJson(response.toMap))
```

This would convert your `HashMap` to a `Map` which can be written as json without additional code.

Comment: i tried it but it giving me can not write an instanse of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonNode to http response try to define a writable[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonNode]

Comment: It seems you imported the wrong package. Make sure you imported `play.api.libs.json.Json`

Comment: its not working properly its giving me {"keyValue":"LoadFactor:0.75"....not giving key's Value

Comment: import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write ,import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats, import play.api.libs.json.Json

Comment: sir, second error its shows :- No json deserializer found for type scala.collection.immutableMa[String,java.util.Map[String,String]] try to implement an implicit write or format for this type...

Comment: Why would you use `java.util.Map`? `scala.collection.immutable.Map` is the only Map that can be serialized without implementing writes or formats

Comment: thank you sir, java.util.Map to scala.collection.immutable.Map ...its working ...

Comment: Why do you have Lift's JSON library *and* Play's?  That's just going to be a source of confusion.  Drop the Lift stuff.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution would be to use JSON4s. [https://github.com/json4s/json4s]
As additional gain it gives you a nice DSL, the abilitity to use Jackson or not and a great way to deserialize JSON.

```
scala> import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

scala> implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
formats: org.json4s.Formats{val dateFormat: org.json4s.DateFormat; val typeHints:org.json4s.TypeHints} = org.json4s.Serialization$$anon$1@f40c08d

scala> Serialization.write(Map("test" -> "a", "test 2" -> 2))
res1: String = {"test":"a","test 2":2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
val data = response.map(value=> value._1 -> Json.toJson(value._2))

Ok(json.toJson(data.toMap))
```

Comment: its giving compile time error ............No json deserializer found for type java.util.map[String,String] try implement implicit write or format for this type.

Comment: then try convert map to list like     response.map(value=> value._1 -> Json.toJson(value._2.toList))

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try like this....

var ls: ListBuffer[(String, Map[String, String])] = ListBuffer()
val res = list1.toList.iterator

while (res.hasNext) {

  ls += (("id", getMyMap().toMap))
}
println(ls);
ls.toList
ok(write(ls.toMap))


def getMyMap(): scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String] = {

var m=scala.collection.mutable.Map("Address" -> "strt1", "Mobile" -> 98974)
 m
}
```

Output:

```
{"0":{"Address":"strt1","Mobile":"98974"}}
```